# Can I modify bitcoin as per my requirement?

Tags: bitcoind

I have taken bitcoin code,and have builded the coin successfully, now i want to change the parameters of my coin so could it possibe suppose i want to define parameters like `i want to generate total three lakhs of BTC per year and initial coin to transfer will be 20% of two lakhs BTC`,so could it be possible?
Thank You in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create your own chain (and thereby your own coin) with a different Genesis block and changing the subsidy schedule to your liking, thereby modifying the consensus rules from the original Bitcoin chain.

The `subsidy schedule` is currently only a function of block height of the strong chain, adjusted with halvings every 210k blocks. You could parameterise initial subsidy and halving schedule to fit the subsidy schedule you describe above on an annual rate.

Depending on the Bitcoin implementation you choose to work with, the parametrisation of the subsidy factors in the code may vary, but is definitely possible.

Regarding the `initial coin transfer`, you can design your subsidy schedule to begin with a certain amount, so the coinbase subsidy reward in your Genesis block represents the value you describe.